# What are employers looking for when they ask to see sample code with CV for a Senior PHP Developer position

Tags: applications

When the employer says in the "How to apply" section:

> please submit your application (Cover letter, CV, and code samples - on executable files)

all is easy except that part that says "and code samples - on executable files", What do they expect a fully functional small website, OOP classes set get, ...
if they would has said write us a code that does 123 that would been much better. anyone got any ideas

Comment: If you have a github account I'd just link to that and maybe include a couple of the highlights as attachments.

Answer (score 6):

I **guess** this is a typo and should read "*no* executable files" (because viruses).

You should probably **check back with them**, asking what they are looking for as executables specifically, and have them tell you if it's a typo or not.

Because, *should* they actually be looking for executables, it makes big a big difference, what systems they're working with and they should specify that.

Comment: I guess it is a typo, php position and executable!!!

Comment: **Can** be done :) But don't. Seriously.

Comment: This does seem like the most likely explanation, but yeah, check back with them and confirm!

Comment: they confirmed it is a typo, but this is not the accepted answer you only pointed out the typo.

Comment: @Waqleh your choice to make